# NetSuite Customize Contact -> Role list

Tags: netsuite, roles, contacts, role

In NetSuite need to add new Contact -> Role(s) the the [list of roles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcTvC.png) a Contact can have. Where is this done at?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list of Contact Roles is accessible via ***Setup > Sales > CRM Lists***. You might need to expand the "Filter" section at the top to make the Type dropdown visible, and then select "Contact Role" from the dropdown options.

Comment: This shows where they are, however after adding a new one from the "New" button at the top left of that page, the new "Contact Role" is not showing up in our list when we "Update Primary" and edit the roles of contacts for a company.

Comment: @JoshuaFricke I've had that happen as well and after a while they appeared, so I'm guessing that there is some caching or something going on in the backend.

Comment: I just tested and you are correct my new "Contact Roles" are now visible. I wonder what the refresh rate is on those. That would be helpful to know for testing the addition of new items.